# How to make if statement work in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

My code is like this

```
Sub A()

Dim I, Q, C_Count As Integer
C_Count = Worksheets("0618").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

For I = 7 To C_Count
 
  Q = Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, I).Value

  If 0 < Q < 30 Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, I).Value
 
  End If

Next

End Sub
```

But the If statement doesn't work at all.
I wanted to make

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, I).Value
```

work only when Q is over 0 and under 30. But It also works when it is zero!
Is there any problem with my IF statement?

Comment: 1) `If 0 < Q < 30` should be `If 0 < Q and Q < 30`. 2) Remove the `End If`, you do not need that if your `Then` codes are in the same line as `If...Then` OR Alternatively, move `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, I).Value` to next line and it should work still.

Comment: FYI - For future question, please wrap your code in the proper code block so that it's easier to read, thanks!

Comment: Also - `Dim I, Q, C_Count As Integer` means `Dim I As Variant, Q As Variant, C_Count As Integer` - you probably meant `Dim I As Integer, Q As Integer, C_Count As Integer`

Comment: Wow I didn't know that! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transpose Values with Condition

- The following solutions all do the same. In a nutshell, they transpose the values from a one-row range (depending on the values of another same sized one-row range) to a one-column range in another worksheet.

**`For...Next` Using `Cells`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ForNext()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("0618")
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sws.Rows(2).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty row
    Dim slCol As Long: slCol = slCell.Column
    If slCol < 7 Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 7 To slCol
        cValue = sws.Cells(9, c).Value
        Set dCell = dws.Cells(c - 1, 3) ' "-1 = - 7 + 6"
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If cValue > 0 And cValue < 30 Then
                Set sCell = sws.Cells(2, c)
                dCell.Value = sCell.Value
            Else
                dCell.Value = Empty
            End If
        Else
            dCell.Value = Empty
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub ForNextConstants()

    Const sName As String = "0618" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const sRow As Long = 2 ' Source Row
    Const sfCol As Long = 7 ' Source First Column
    Const hlRow As Long = 9 ' Source Hi-Lo Row
    Const hlLo As Double = 0 ' Sourc Lo
    Const hlHi As Double = 30 ' Source Hi
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const dfRow As Long = 6 ' Destination First Row
    Const dCol As Long = 3 ' Destination Column
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sws.Rows(sRow).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty row
    Dim slCol As Long: slCol = slCell.Column
    If slCol < sfCol Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = sfCol To slCol
        cValue = sws.Cells(hlRow, c).Value
        Set dCell = dws.Cells(c - sfCol + dfRow, dCol)
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If cValue > hlLo And cValue < hlHi Then
                Set sCell = sws.Cells(sRow, c)
                dCell.Value = sCell.Value
            Else
                dCell.Value = Empty
            End If
        Else
            dCell.Value = Empty
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**`For Each...Next` Using Ranges**

```
Sub ForEach()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("0618")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rcCount As Long
    With sws.Range("G2")
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(, sws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty row range
        rcCount = slCell.Column - .Column + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(, rcCount)
    End With
    
    Dim hlrg As Range: Set hlrg = srg.EntireColumn.Rows(9)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("C6").Resize(rcCount)
    
    Dim hlCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    For Each hlCell In hlrg.Cells
        n = n + 1
        cValue = hlCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If cValue > 0 And cValue < 30 Then
                drg.Cells(n).Value = srg.Cells(n).Value
            Else
                drg.Cells(n).Value = Empty
            End If
        Else
            drg.Cells(n).Value = Empty
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub ForEachConstants()

    Const sName As String = "0618" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const sFirst As String = "G2" ' Source First Cell
    Const hlRow As Long = 9 ' Source Hi-Lo Row
    Const hlLo As Double = 0 ' Sourc Lo
    Const hlHi As Double = 30 ' Source Hi
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const dFirst As String = "C6" ' Destination First Cell
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rcCount As Long
    With sws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(, sws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty row range
        rcCount = slCell.Column - .Column + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(, rcCount)
    End With
    
    Dim hlrg As Range: Set hlrg = srg.EntireColumn.Rows(hlRow)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(rcCount)
    
    Dim hlCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    For Each hlCell In hlrg.Cells
        n = n + 1
        cValue = hlCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If cValue > hlLo And cValue < hlHi Then
                drg.Cells(n).Value = srg.Cells(n).Value
            Else
                drg.Cells(n).Value = Empty
            End If
        Else
            drg.Cells(n).Value = Empty
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```